# Ruby difference in arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

Write a program that takes as input a list of n integers and produces as output the largest difference obtained by subtracting an integer in the list from the one following it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking us to write code.

Comment: Isn't this always the largest value minus the smallest value? Are you asking to sort an array?

Comment: "[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)"

Answer (score 1):

I can think of this using the [`combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-combination) method.

```
ar = (1..12).to_a
ar.combination(2).max_by { |a,b| b - a }
# => [1, 12]
ar = [1,23,56,11]
# => [1, 23, 56, 11]
ar.combination(2).max_by { |a,b| (b - a).abs }
# => [1, 56]
```

It seems I misunderstood the line as OP mentioned :

> output the largest difference obtained by subtracting an integer in the list from the one following it

Here is the correct one :-

```
ar = [1,23,56,11]
ar.each_cons(2).max_by { |a, b| (b - a).abs }
# => [56, 11]
```